# redirect a user based on Rolegroup

Tags: asp.net

I have a pretty simple method I'm calling on Page load, it looks like this

```
  Protected Sub identify()

    If User.Identity.IsAuthenticated Then

    Else
        Response.Redirect("login.aspx")
    End If
End Sub
```

What I want to do is throw a redirect depending on the role group the user is a part of. So if they are authenticated, but not part of the "Admins" user group, I'd redirect them to a different page....something like

```
  Protected Sub identify()

    If User.Identity.IsAuthenticated Then
       If user.Identiy.IsInRoleGroup("Admin")
         Response.Redirect("AdministratorDefault.aspx")
       End If
    Else
        Response.Redirect("login.aspx")
    End If
End Sub
```

Is something like this possible? I can't find an answer.

Comment: You can use the `User.IsInRole()` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsprincipal.isinrole.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`If (User.IsInRole("Administrator"))
  ...
 End If`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsprincipal.isinrole.aspx

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much. Worked like a charm.